# In FormFlow, How do i get the form values after form is done?

Tags: botframework

I have a complete Form that has different fields. Name, phone and so on.

Before complition, I would like to send the fields to a method then then sends an email. More specificly, I want to put the values on a dictionary and then pass it to the method.

Where are those values stored in the Form so I can get them?

This is my code

```
form.OnCompletion(processOrder);

                var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
                            {
                               { "tileid", "open" },
                               { "src", "Facebook" },
                               { "chid", "9" },
                               { "apply-first-name",  "xxx" },
                               { "apply-last-name", "xxx" },
                               { "apply-email", "xxx" }
                            };
                sendAsync(parameters);

                return form.Build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. All values are inside the ”state” objekt passed to the oncompletion method.